# Trouble with file properties

Tags: c#, file

I want to list all the files and all its properties (name,size,etc) in a directory but i only managed to get the names of the files. here's the code

```
 <table>
    @foreach(var fileName in Directory.GetFiles("C:/baba"))
    {
    <tr><td>@Path.GetFileName(fileName)</td></tr>
    }
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows");

            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + file.Name + "\r\nSize: " + file.Length + "\r\nType: " + file.GetType());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:
[image: Program output]

Comment: Be aware that `file.GetType()` will return a .NET `Type` object of type `FileInfo`, not the type of the file on disk. EDIT: Well I guess it's clear now that you added a screenshot...

Comment: @Vache That is true.  Just threw this together to show an example of using DirectoryInfo.  I'll leave it up to the OP to decide what/which info he wants.  The program is just an example of what's possible.

Comment: how can i get the file type like png or jpeg, mp3 etc then?

Comment: You can add this line: 'Console.WriteLine("Extension: " + Path.GetExtension(dir + " " + file));'

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DirectoryInfo` class instead. It returns an object instead of a string and it contains more information. The equivalent method would be [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).